# Adding the order currency to the order note woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I'm trying to write a function which adds the currency the customer paid for the online order to the customer's order notes in woocommerce. The function I've written looks like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_currency',  1, 1  );
    function add_currency( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
    $note = $order_currency;
    $order->add_order_note( $note );
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

[image: Here's an image of the order note I'm trying to affect]

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you mean by customer order notes? which location? because they appear in multiple locations in WooCommerce. maybe with a screenshot?

Comment: @7uc1f3r I have included a screenshot, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As I see you didn't declare the **$order_currency** yet.

You can get the currency related strings by the following mode:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$currency_code = $order->get_currency();
$currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency_code );
```